# Null property in XML Beans optional field

Tags: java, coding-style, complexity-theory, xmlbeans

I am in a situation where I get some fields from a dto to insert them in an xmlBean, for example:

```
xmlBeanItem.setProperty(dtoItem.getproperty());
```

The problem is in that if for any reason dtoItem.getproperty() returned null, the xmlBean Property generates an empty tag (for instance  ).

Is there a way to avoid such situation without using the famous if condition? So far I have used it on the form:

```
if (dtoItem.getJustification() != null) {
     xmlBeanItem.setProperty(dtoItem.getproperty());
}
```

which would increase the cyclomatic complexity to an astronomical number !!.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no other way.  In XmlSchema, null and absence are two distinct concepts.  That is why there are xmlbean.isSetXXX() and xmlbean.isNilXXX() getters for each property.